# Adding elements into associative array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, associative-array

I'm trying to add elements into an Associative Array, which is `colors = []`
I want it to have the `["id":selected_color]` but my browser keeps crashing (an infinite loop somewhere?)

I'm not sure if I'm adding the elements into the array correctly.

What is happening is that I'm clicking on a span element, which has its ID value set to a hexcode value, and I'm trying to capture that value and associate it with the `selected._color`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var selected_color = "";
var colors = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".color_cell").click(function(){
        // ADD MY COLOR TO SELECTED COLOR'S ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY       
        colors[$(this).attr("id")] = selected_color;
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        $(this).css({'background-color':'white'});
        $(this).unbind('click');
        updateDisplay(colors);
        alert("hi");
    });

    $(".btnColor").click(function(){
         // MAKE SELECTED COLOR BE ME
        alert("hey");
        selected_color = $(this).attr("id");
    }); // end button handler
}); // end ready()

function updateDisplay(colors) {
    jQuery.each(colors, function(key, value) {
        //it seems to crash here...
        $("#storage_display").html("var "+$("#storage_display").html()+" " +value);
    });
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried making your example work, but my brain exploded so I just came up with my own. Enjoy! http://jsfiddle.net/2BdEJ/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're defining colors as an array instead of an object.

You just need to initialize it properly:

```
 var colors = {}; // or new Object();
```

---

Additional suggestion... there's really no need for the jQuery.each here.  Iterating over an associative array like this (let's not argue the semantics of whether you can actually call this an associative array) looks like this:

```
function updateColors(colors)
{
    for (var key in colors)
    {
        $("#storage_display").html("var "+$("#storage_display").html()+" " +colors[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to explain the above, there are no associative arrays as such in Javascript, but properties of objects can be set with that syntax, i.e. `colors.test="hello"` is the same as `colors['test']="hello"`

Comment: I changed my code and initialized using `var colors = {};` :

and I tried it to `colors{$(this).attr("id")} = selected_color;`

and also tried `colors[$(this).attr("id")] = selected_color;`

I'm sorry, but I guess I don't quite understand what is going on here. I understand that it should come out to what @waitinforatrain said, but I go to my console to see if it's picking up anything after I click by injecting `var colors[0];` and tried `var colors{0}` but it returns syntax errors.

Comment: Here's a demo of your code with the `{}`: http://jsfiddle.net/waitinforatrain/rDBaJ/ . Tell me what you expect to happen that doesn't happen

Comment: @Richard Lu - Waitinforatrain's fiddle is good.  You have multiple problems above...  Your 2nd syntax (`colors[$(this).attr("id")] = selected_color;` is correct, but perhaps you have another issue going on.  `var colors[0]`; is just an error, as would `var colors{0}`.  First, you create the object (`var colors = {};`), then you can access it (`var foo = colors['red'];`).

Comment: This is making me go nuts. I tried `var foo = colors['red'];` but it returned undefined. I'm not sure what foo means.      

I tried initializing to `var colors = new Array();` which actually works. I can see that the values are showing up in the console.   

For my `updateDisplay(colors)` function I'm trying to have it show up my information in #storage_display something like: `var selected_color = ["hexcode", "hexcode", "hexcode"]` so verbatim would be like `var black = ["#000000", "#200000"]` and etc as I continue to add colors.      
Thanks for the continuing support. You guys are awesome.

Comment: `colors['red']` is undefined until you define it.  'red' is a key into the object (or, if you will, associative array).  Can you just post more code?  It would be trivial to fix if we knew what 'selected_color' was supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try just some normal javascript instead of

```
colors[$(this).attr("id")] = selected_color;
```

try using

```
colors.push(selected_color);
```

and instead of your jquery loop, try using

```
for(var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    $('#storage_display').html('whatever your trying to do here use colors[i]');
}
```

I dont understand what you're trying to do in the loop but assuming it did work, the html will be something like 'var var var var var var hexcode hexcode hexcode hexcode hexcode'

Comment: This solution drops the 'selected_color' entirely.  If you wanted to do this using a standard array, it would be something more like `colors.push({'id':$(this).attr('id'),'val':selected_color});`.  Of course, as soon as you start creating an array of name-value pairs which have no explicit need for indexing... you should just use an associative array.  : )

Comment: Oops yeah thats a typo. As far as I can see there is no use of the 'key' and no reason for this to not just be a normal array if all that is needed is a loop.

Comment: They key solution will intrinsically remove duplicates, but I agree... there's no real reason other than that.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from everything that was mentioned before ID attributes must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z . That might crash your browser.

Also if you are only storing colors in your array why not use just a normal array? (as James suggests)